# Solving equations involving fractional exponents?

Tags: exponentiation, fractions

Let's say we have the following equation (with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$): $$x^\frac{a}{b} = 2$$

If the exponent is an even integer, we get two solutions. If it is an odd integer, we get only one solution. How about the other cases and how do I write the result in closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then do $$\left (x^{a/b}\right )^b=2^b,$$ gives you the equation $x^a=2^b.$ This one you know how to solve.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem! I didn't see the forest for the trees ;-)

Comment: @Marc I understand. You are welcome!